# MySQL slow queries and memcached

Tags: mysql, performance, memcached

I have slow query cached with memcached, it wokrs fine, but sometimes we got a lot of slow queries in mysql as if memcached had stopped and then our website going down.

Slow queries graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJk8R.png

At this moment we got about 100 slow queries in 30 seconds. What сan it be?
Our query:

```
# Query_time: 5.942602  Lock_time: 0.010214 Rows_sent: 10000  Rows_examined: 493139  

SET timestamp=1335194149;  
SELECT story_id FROM dug_stories d WHERE d.story_is_permanent=0  AND  
                       (  
                        (d.story_time>1335190543 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 5)  
                        OR  
                        ( ( (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 12 OR (d.story_pluses >= 10 AND d.story_minuses<=0) )  AND d.story_cat!=48 AND d.st  
ory_cat!=131 AND d.story_cat!=55 AND d.story_cat!=44 AND d.story_cat!=126 AND d.story_cat!=53 AND d.story_cat!=370 AND d.story_cat!=381 AND d.stor  
y_cat!=304 AND d.story_cat!=497)  OR (d.story_cat=48 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 9) OR (d.story_cat=131 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_min  
uses) > 8) OR (d.story_cat=55 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 8) OR (d.story_cat=44 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 9) OR (d.story_c  
at=126 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 13) OR (d.story_cat=53 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 8) OR (d.story_cat=370 AND (d.story_pl  
uses-d.story_minuses) > 8) OR (d.story_cat=381 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 8) OR (d.story_cat=304 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses)  
> 8) OR (d.story_cat=497 AND (d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses) > 9)  
                       )  
                       ORDER BY d.story_rating DESC, d.story_time DESC LIMIT 0, 10000;
```

**SLIGHTLY Adjusted query (instead of all the != categories, I changed to NOT Category IN (list of categories to exclude), but formatted for easier readability... ALSO, note, the SET TIMESTAMP variable was not even being used in the query... it was a hard-coded value.**

```
SET timestamp=1335194149;  
SELECT 
      story_id 
   FROM 
      dug_stories d 
   WHERE 
          d.story_is_permanent = 0  
      AND (     ( d.story_time > 1335190543 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 5 )  
             OR (    (    d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 12 
                       OR (   d.story_pluses >= 10 AND d.story_minuses <= 0 ) 
                     )  
                  AND NOT d.story_cat IN ( 44, 48, 53, 55, 126, 131, 304, 370, 381, 497 )
                )
             OR ( d.story_cat = 44  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 9 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 48  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 9 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 53  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 55  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 126 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 13 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 131 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 304 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 370 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 381 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
             OR ( d.story_cat = 497 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 9 )  
          )  
   ORDER BY 
      d.story_rating DESC, 
      d.story_time DESC 
   LIMIT 
      0, 10000;
```

Thanks a lot for help!
And sorry for my poor english :)

Answer (score 0):

The slow log may indicate that indexes aren't being fully utilized if the rows_examined is larger than the result set.

Ideally, MySQL should be able to utilize a single index for all filter expressions in the WHERE clause. Your WHERE clause is very complex due to all of the nested ANDs and ORs and the reference to multiple columns. MySQL is probably not able to utilize an index for optimizing this query, even if you have one.

Generally, this type of query can be improved by dividing it up into several smaller queries that are each able to utilize an index, and combining the results into a single query using `UNION`.

For example, if I have an index on first_name and an index on last_name, the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE active = true
  AND ((first_name = 'Marcus') OR (last_name = 'Adams'))
```

Can be improved like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE active = true
  AND first_name = 'Marcus'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE active = true
  AND last_name = 'Adams'
```

The fact that there are more rows being examined than the 10000 in your LIMIT clause also indicates that the ORDER BY clause may be utilizing file sort, rather than the query returning the rows already in order. This makes MySQL do all of the work, even though you only want a portion of the records. You will most likely need to utilize a covering index that handles all of your criteria, which may be impossible, or you will need to drop the ORDER BY clause, or, as you indicated, rely on caching to save the day.

Query time is a poor performance measurement on a server with high load because any query may be slow on a busy server. You should use `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW PROFILE` to profile your queries and improve them so that they do not put too much load on your server.

Allowing too many threads to run on a server can cause a cascading effect, bringing your server to a halt. If you are using InnoDB, ensure that your [thread concurrency](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/06/05/innodb-thread-concurrency/) is not too high. It is better to make everybody wait and serve 8 threads at a time (very quickly), rather than try to serve 100 or unlimited threads at once (very slowly).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from my adjusting the query for readability, I would try restructuring the query a bit more.
I would ensure you have an index on ( Story_Is_Permanent, Story_Cat, Story_Time )

I would assume you have a "Story Category" table with literal description for presentation to the user.  Since you are querying all categories anyhow, but only based on certain ones you either want to INCLUDE or EXCLUDE... and if INCLUDING, its only based on a net count of PLUSES vs MINUSES for the category.  I would add to columns to that category table... something like

```
DefaultToInclude   integer as 1 or 0
PlusMinusNetCount  integer
```

Then, do a join to the category table and simplify your query, something like

```
SELECT 
      story_id 
   FROM 
      dug_stories d
         JOIN YourCategories YC
            on d.story_cat = YC.categoryID
   WHERE 
          d.story_is_permanent = 0  
      AND (     ( d.story_time > 1335190543 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 5 )  
             OR (     YC.DefaultToInclude = 0 
                  AND (    d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 12 
                       OR (d.story_pluses >= 10 AND d.story_minuses <= 0 ) 
                      )  
                )
             OR (     YC.DefaultToInclude = 1 
                  AND d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses > YC.PlusMinusNetCount )
          )
 ORDER BY 
      d.story_rating DESC, 
      d.story_time DESC 
   LIMIT 
      0, 10000;
```

**The**

```
(     YC.DefaultToInclude = 0 
  AND (    d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 12 
        OR (d.story_pluses >= 10 AND d.story_minuses <= 0 ) 
      )  
)
```

**would ultimately replace the**

```
OR (    (    d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 12 
          OR (   d.story_pluses >= 10 AND d.story_minuses <= 0 ) 
        )  
    AND d.story_cat!=48 
    AND d.story_cat!=131 
    AND d.story_cat!=55 
    AND d.story_cat!=44 
    AND d.story_cat!=126 
    AND d.story_cat!=53 
    AND d.story_cat!=370 
    AND d.story_cat!=381 
    AND d.story_cat!=304 
    AND d.story_cat!=497 
   )
```

**The**

```
 OR (     YC.DefaultToInclude = 1 
      AND d.story_pluses-d.story_minuses > YC.PlusMinusNetCount )
```

**would then ultimately replace the**

```
( OR ( d.story_cat = 44  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 9 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 48  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 9 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 53  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 55  AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 126 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 13 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 131 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 304 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 370 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 381 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 8 ) 
  OR ( d.story_cat = 497 AND d.story_pluses - d.story_minuses > 9 ) 
)
```

This allows flexibility to simply include/exclude another category with its respective "net" count without having to oooopps add more OR / AND conditions to your already lengthy query.  No mattre what, it appears it will ALWAYS have to go through the entire "dug_Stories" table since you are looking at every category for one condition and every other category for another.  Your timestamp is only for the NOT EQUAL categories, but your other condition does not have any timestamp restriction (unless that was a mistake in your query as presented).